# AssetBundle Upgrade

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, assetbundle

Unity 4.0.0 -> Unity 4.5.4
I need AssetBundle upgrade to adapt new Unity version.

In Unity 4.5.4 develoment environment, I have previous version of AssetBundle. So, when I try to play the game, Unity float an error that my AssetBundle need to be upgraded to new version.

But, I don't know how I have to upgrade my AssetBundle at all. I want to make AssetBundle in Unity 4.5.4 by using only AssetBundles of Unity 4.0.0. Is it possible?

Otherwise, do I have to use Assets like resources files to make new version of AssetBundles?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Unity offers any support for migrating AssetBundles that are already created.

What you need to do is to get the files that you used for the asset bundle creation in Unity 4.0.0 and use the same process to re-create them in Unity 4.5.4.